# WebDeploy - just can't get it to work

Tags: visual-studio, iis, deployment, msdeploy, msdeployserviceagent

I've installed Web Deploy 2.1 on a Server 2008 R2 running under VMWare.

In the IIS Manager (Management Service applet) I can see that "Enable Remote Connections" is checked and the port is set to 8172.  Under "IIS Manager Permissions" I've added my Windows account (CORP\ekkis) and under the "Authentication" applet (for IIS) I have enabled "Windows Authentication".

I've also turned off the firewall.

So from the command line I test the system to work like this:

```
C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V2>msdeploy -verb:dump -source:contentPath=\temp,wmsvc=192.168.0.70,username=CORP\ekkis,password=MyPass,authType=Basic -allowUntrusted=True
```

and get this:

```
Info: Using ID '9b954a0f-ff07-4e77-ba2c-d27472f5fda0' for connections to the rem
ote server.
Error Code: ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED
More Information: Connected to the destination computer ("192.168.0.70") using t
he Web Management Service, but could not authorize. Make sure that you are using
 the correct user name and password, that the site you are connecting to exists,
 and that the credentials represent a user who has permissions to access the sit
e.
Error: Object of type 'contentPath' and path '\temp' cannot be created.
Error: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
Error count: 1.
```

I've also tried deploying with Visual Studio 2010 from the host OS with the following service urls (I haven't found proper documentation on how to form this url):

```
https://192.168.0.70/
https://192.168.0.70:8172/
https://192.168.0.70:8172/MsDeployAgentService/
https://192.168.0.70/MsDeployAgentService/
```

I've tried the non-secure versions as well but just cannot get it to work.  What is the correct format for the url? and what permissions am I missing?

the errors from VS have varied depending on how I attempt it but below is a sample:

```
Could not complete the request to remote agent URL 'http://192.168.0.70:8172//MSDEPLOYAGENTSERVICE'.
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
Publish failed to deploy.
```

there really should be a guide out there to do this (yes, I've googled myself blue in the face)!

thanks - ekkis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok, I've figured out that the correct url is:

```
https://192.168.0.70:8172/MsDeploy.axd
```

and that having the "Windows Authentication" enabled doesn't seem to make a difference.  Also, having my account in the "Managers" list doesn't seem to make a difference either.

so the back end was all working fine (I've turned off the Web Deployment Agent Service).  it was just the url I had wrong.